# Unescape twice escaped title in rss

Tags: go, escaping, rss, unescapestring

I got some rss with strange escaped titles, for example:

```
<title>S&amp;amp;P 500 : Wall Street amorce un rebond, Binance fait l&amp;apos;objet d&amp;apos;une enquête de la SEC</title>
```

the whole rss: https://www.dailyfx.com/francais/feeds/actualites-marches-financiers

opera browser shows such news titles correctly as follows

> S&P 500 : Wall Street amorce un rebond, Binance fait l'objet d'une
> enquête de la SEC

How can I correctly unescape news for the case normally I receive once-escaped news, and for the case above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence `&amp;` encodes a `&` sign. But if the content ought to be HTML for example, that may contain further HTML escape sequences.

For example if the text to display contains `&`, in HTML it would be encoded as `&amp;`. If you insert this text into an XML, the first character `&` also has to be escaped which results in `&amp;amp;`.

To get the human-readable decoded text, you have to parse the XML and decode as HTML. You may use [`html.UnescapeString()`](https://pkg.go.dev/html#UnescapeString).

For example:

```
const src = `<title>S&amp;amp;P 500 : Wall Street amorce un rebond, Binance fait l&amp;apos;objet d&amp;apos;une enquête de la SEC</title>`

var s string
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s)

s = html.UnescapeString(s)
fmt.Println(s)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/icQJo4PEwDm)):

```
S&amp;P 500 : Wall Street amorce un rebond, Binance fait l&apos;objet d&apos;une enquête de la SEC
S&P 500 : Wall Street amorce un rebond, Binance fait l'objet d'une enquête de la SEC
```